# Why is Entity Framework slow despite only selecting a small portion with take()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I've been working with EF for a while now, but usually not with huge amounts of data - that is until now.

I try to extract about 600.000 rows from our database, but use serverside paging (`.Take()`) to only select 50 at a time. But even selecting these 50 rows takes almost 1 minute. The same goes for applying filters and such. I'm really confused as to why EF reacts that way.

The following is the function I use for paging. After that I use AutoMapper to convert the `CrmObject` objects to the view model (`CrmObjectGridVM`). The conversion is the part that takes about 1 minute.

```
public static IEnumerable<CrmObject> ApplyPaging(this IEnumerable<CrmObject> data, int page, int pageSize)
{
        if (pageSize > 0 && page > 0)
        {
            data = data.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize);
        }

        data = data.Take(pageSize);

        return data;
}

var data = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CrmObjectGridVM>>(objectData)
```

At first I thought it might have something to do with AutoMapper, but all the AutoMapper should do is iterate through the data that should already be minimized to the 50 rows I want to select.

I really would like to understand what exactly is going on.

Comment: EF is an ORM. It merely generates queries. Profile those queries if you want to know what's going on. Edit: oh, you use IEnumerable. Show all relevant code. It looks like you're pulling the entire table and are filtering in-memory.

Comment: Please make sure that there's a (covering) index on your database table that you are working with. This has a *massive* impact on performance, even if you are dealing with small numbers of rows (600k rows is far from being a huge amount of data).

Comment: I can't see the internal query after Skip()/Take() is executed.

Comment: I somehow doubt that a covering index helps me much, because the selection itself is really basic. It's like SELECT * FROM CrmObjects WHERE jobId = 1 and that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `IEnumerable{T}` instead of `IQueryable{T}`. `IEnumerable{T}` methods will execute locally, so your `Skip` statement will iterate all records in the database table (up to the given number).

Change your method to use `IQueryable{T}` instead, this will allow the provider to optimise it into SQL.

```
public static IQueryable<CrmObject> ApplyPaging(this IQueryable<CrmObject> data, int page, int pageSize)
{
    if (pageSize > 0 && page > 0)
    {
        data = data.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize);
    }

    data = data.Take(pageSize);

    return data;
}

var data = objectData.ProjectTo<CrmObjectGridVM>();
```

Comment: A little addition as you have to use ProjectTo like so: var data = objectData.ProjectTo<CrmObjectGridVM>();